# How to change the box color based on the class value

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a code in a loop like this

```
<td id = box, class =<%= book_ty(article)%>><%= article.book_type %></td>
```

When the `book_ty` equal to `x` the box will become red color, if it is `y` the box will be orange color. Now the colors are directly applied to `article.book_type` I want apply that colors to `id`

I define a method in `articles.helper.rb` i.e

```
def book_ty(article)
 case article.book_type
  when "x"
     "x"
  when "y"
     "y"
  when "z"
     "z"
end
end
```

in `article.scss`

```
.x {
  color: red;
}
.y{
  color: orange;
}
.z{
  color: green;
}

#box {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 display: inline;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

How to change the box color based on the class value?

Comment: What kind of question is this? "`How to get css id based on class value`" and then at end this "`How to change the box color based on the class value?`" first decide what you are trying to ask, then write the same as heading.

Comment: Please refer this doc: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#help-post-body

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a helper method for it, `article.book_type` already return the class for `td`.

```
<td id="box" class="<%= article.book_type %>"><%= article.book_type %></td>
```

But your title still unclear for me

*How to get css id based on class value?*

Comment: yeah, i already tried with that, but the styles are not applying for box.

Answer (score 0):

If I parsed the question properly, you want to modify your css to:

```
#box .x { color: red }
```

and so on. The above will apply the color to the elements, having `class="x"` and `id="box"`.

Or, you might change the ruby to:

```
<td id="box_<%= book_ty(article)%>"><%= article.book_type %></td>
```

and modify `css` to:

```
#box_x { color: red }
```

Or, combine the solutions above.